# Unable to remove installer created by Advanced Installer

Tags: advanced-installer

I am unable to remove this installer application created using Advanced Installer. It gives me below error. Anyone let me know how to forcefully remove this application.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic Windows Installer error message and usually occurs when there is a custom action failing during installation/uninstall process. Try to run the uninstall process using a log option

```
msiexec /x {ProductCode_Guid} /L*V uninstall.log
```

and check which one of the uninstall custom action returns a value of 3 ([this means an error occurred](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html)). Most likely there is something wrongly configured for that custom action or its code implementation simply throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.  This worked for me.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d